# AngularJS - an easier way to bind one to one and one to many relationships?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am going through the angular tutorial where you build a phone informational website and at the same time I am exploring more complicated data structures that one would see in a real enterprise application using grails restful json services; such as adding to the Phone model a form factor which is a one to one relationship and also adding multiple patents that cover the Phone entity in a one to many relationship.

Is there an easier way than below to bind the HTML to the different model data structures such that a one to one and a one to many relationship doesn't require the non-ellegant use of ng-repeat?

Ideally I'd like a simpler way than nesting ng-repeat elements to grab the description for the formFactor and having to nest 3 deep ng-repeats in order to list the sub-record information for each patent object when I am using ng-repeat to list each phone.

Is a simpler method possible than the one shown below?

This is the Angular-ized HTML:

```
<div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="phone in phones | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">{{phone.name}} <span ng-repeat="formFactor in formFactors | filter:phone.formFactor.id">({{formFactor.description}})</span></h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text">{{phone.snippet}}</p>
        <hr />
        <p><span class="list-group-item-heading">Patents covering phone:</span>
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="phPat in phone.patents"><span ng-repeat="patent in patents | filter:{id:phPat.id}">{{patent.patentNumber + ': ' + patent.patentAbstract}}</span></li>
            </ul>
        </p>
    </a>
</div>
```

This is the angular controller code:

```
var templateApp = angular.module('templateApp', []);

templateApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$location',
    function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location)
{
    $http.get('phone/index').success(function(data)
    {
        $scope.phones = data;
    });

    $http.get('formFactors.json').success(function(data)
    {
        $scope.formFactors = data;
    });

    $http.get('formFactors.json').success(function(data)
    {
        $scope.formFactors = data;
    });

    $scope.orderProp = 'age';
}]);
```

This is the JSON the web services return:
phone/index:

```
[
    {
        "class": "package.Phone",
        "id": "12",
        "age": 4,
        "formFactor": {
            "id": 10
        },
        "imageURL": "asdf",
        "name": "Motorola DEFY with MOTOBLUR",
        "patents": [
            {
                "id": 9
            },
            {
                "id": 7
            },
            ...
        ],
        "snippet": "Are you ready for everything life throws your way?"
    },
    ...
]
```

formFactors.json:

```
[
    {
        "id": 12,
        "description": "tablet"
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "description": "smartphone"
    },
    ...
]
```

patents.json:

```
[
    {
        "id": 9
        "patentAbstract": "four score...",
        "patentNumber": "789"
    },
    {
        "id": 8
        "patentAbstract": "lorem ipsum....",
        "patentNumber": "456"
    }
    ...
]
```

**update:** Thanks to the answer below this is what I ended up writing in the controller so that all the data is immediately available directly to the template so we don't have to do any of that nasty triple nesting ng-repeats:

```
angular.forEach($scope.phones, function(phone,i) 
{
    phone.formFactor = angular.findWhere($scope.formFactors, {id:phone.formFactor.id});

    angular.forEach(phone.patents, function(phPat, i) 
    {
        if(typeof phone.patentInfo == 'undefined') 
        {
            phone.patentInfo = $filter('filter')($scope.patents, {id:phPat.id});
        } 
        else 
        {
            phone.patentInfo.push( $filter('filter')($scope.patents, {id:phPat.id})[0] );
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've struggled with this too but really you encounter this issue anywhere i.e. undescores answer is .findWhere so that you can derive a single object from many based on some simple criteria. If i know i'm going to need to do this in my data set or template I will usually loop through, reference, and then set this data ahead of time so that I don't have to do it in the template.

So if you're grabbing phones and you know that you're going to need to reference a single object from another array as the patent or even many, do the filtering ahead of time in the javascript and set that object or array of objects and a property on each phone so that you don't need to do it in the template.

i.e.

```
$http.get('phone/index').success(function(data)
        {
            $scope.phones = data;
            angular.forEach($scope.phones,function(phone,i) {
               angular.forEach(phone.patents,function(phPat,i){
                    phone.phPat = $filter('filter')(phPat,{id:phPat.id});
                });
            });
        });
```

I got tired of doing a filter just to expose one object so if I know it's going to be a single object in many I use this findWhere function I added.

```
angular.findWhere = function(collection,search) {
    var $filter = angular.element(document).injector().get("$filter"),
        refined = $filter('filter')(collection,search);
    return refined[0];
}
```

Really though in the end you need to have more control over how the data is structured from the get go so that you don't need to loop through a bunch of nested data to expose data.

Comment: This looks like the direction I want to take and it certainly makes the template less clunky; however I am having trouble with this solution - for some reason the changes to the phone object don't seem to propagate to the $scope.phones data, because I do not see a new phPat attribute added to the phones list if I examine it by putting {{phones | json}} into my template code. I figured I needed to modify your code a little bit as well, so I changed the phPat reference inside the filter to be the $scope.patents array since that is the array that contains all the information we need.

Comment: Figured out the issue - I forgot to update my controller to state that it was using the $filter service. Thank you very much!

Comment: your welcome :) yah i figured my example was off since i didn't know your data structure really. Glad you figured it out!